# AngularJS directive: switch statement depending on attribute value

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive which is given as an attribute one of 13 types it can take. Depending on the type the directive should return different HTML elements that represent the given type. The value of the type will be constant - won't change after directive is compiled.

```
<directive type="{{ type }}"></directive>
```

I have an architectural problem. Should I handle all the types inside 1 directive (so that the directive returns different templates depending on `type` value) or differentiate the type cases at the template level into 13 different directives (call a proper type of directive depending on `type` value)? In short should I put the `switch (type)` inside a inside a directive or leave it at the template level?

Then the implementation. What would be the implementation of the proposed solution? In short how to implement that `switch (type)` either inside a directive or a template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is probably easiest to go down the single-directive route, and in which case I can think of two solutions. The best depends on the size of the individual templates.

**Small templates: `ng-switch`**

Give your directive a single HTML file as it's `templateUrl` which contains an `ng-switch` with a `ng-switch-when` case for each `type`. It would look something like this:

```
// directive.js
angular.directive('directive', function() {
    return {
        scope: {type: '@'},
        templateUrl: '/path/to/directive/template.html'
    };
});

// template.html
<div ng-switch="type">
    <div ng-switch-when="somethingType">
        <!-- template for (type === "somethingType") -->
    </div>
    <div ng-switch-when="otherType">
        <!-- template for (type === "otherType") -->
    </div>
    <!-- ... -->
</div>
```

**Large templates: `ng-include`**

Use the same behaviour as in `directive.js` above but keep all your templates within their own individual HTML files local to the directive's directory and then use an `ng-include` to pull in the correct template according to the value of `type`.

```
/path/to/directive
 - /templates
    - somethingType.html
    - otherType.html
 - directive.js
 - template.html

// template.html
<div ng-include="'/path/to/directive/templates/' + type + '.html'"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, that almost fully answers my question. The only issue is that the value of the `type` will be constant - won't change after the directive compilation. Does that change the best way to handle it? Because you said your solution is targetted at the "changing `type`" situation.

Comment: Either solution would work fine for a static value of `type` too. I have removed that caveat from my post - I was just thinking out loud.

Comment: Ok. I thought that maybe for static values there is some other solution. Thanks for helping out!